# UNIX : Editing system crontab (/etc/crontab) and restarting cron services after edit

Tags: linux, unix, cron, cron-task

I want to edit system cron tab (/etc/crontab). I read that crontab -e is the best way to edit crontab and you need not restart cron services if you edit this way. However I am not able to edit /etc/crontab using crontab -e (this command edits the crontab associated with the user, not system crontab). So is there any better way of editing /etc/crontab (other than using VI editor- which I am doing now). Do I need to restart cron services if I edit /etc/crontab using VI edior?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of cronjobs, one is by editing /etc/crontab and sending a SIGHUP the cron daemon. The other way is to use crontab -e to edit
a crontab entry, which is done for the current user or the one mentioned with -u. The -u option can only be used by root. The crontabs
created this way can be found in the directory

> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/

and are named after the user with which uid the jobs will be started. In this case you don't need to SIGHUP cron, a normal user can't do this anyway.
Note: The syntax is slightly different to /etc/crontab: You can't enter an other user name to execute the cronjob.

Comment: Hi Dirk thank you for the detailed info. Currently I am editing /etc/crontab using vi editor and then restart the cron service, I wanted know if this is a good practise or if there is any other better/recommended way of editing /etc/crontab file

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this

```
echo "0 23 * * *      yum -y update > /dev/null 2>&1" >> /var/spool/cron/root
```

Then verify with

```
crontab -l
```